# Change animation speed of Jquery UI Accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, accordion

I'm using the Jquery UI Accordion, and I haven't found anywhere in the documentation on how to change the speed of the animation. I've found people suggest using option "animated: 'bounceslide'" but haven't been able to find what the different available options are for animated.

My current js is as follows

```
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        event: "mouseover",
        animate:"slow",
        active:false
    });
```

The "animate:"slow" is not correct and therefore not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Nope. Nothing seems to work with the UI Accordion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reduce the speed of a accordion in jquery UI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346108/reduce-the-speed-of-a-accordion-in-jquery-ui)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is currently not directly possible, although a feature request has been logged and is scheduled to implemented by the 1.9 milestone: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3772. You can either wait for that release, or try the subclassing method described here: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3533.

This boils down to:

```
$.extend($.ui.accordion.animations, {
  fastslide: function(options) {
    $.ui.accordion.animations.slide(options, { duration: 100 }); }
  });
```

Answer (score 12):

This works fine for me :

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    animate: {
        duration: 500
    }
});
```

Comment: This is, according to current version, the right way to do it nowadays. It is due to when this post was mainly asked versus your answer.

Answer (score 5):

if you set the 'animated' to say swing  then you can set the 'duration' of the animation in milliseconds.
e.g.
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({event: "mouseover", animated: 'swing', duration: 500, active:false
    });

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
speed: 50
```

Where 50 is the number of miliseconds

or

```
speed: 'slow'
```

instead of

```
animate:"slow",
```