# Reduce the speed of a accordion in jquery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I have two problems with this code:

First I would like to reduce the speed of the effect.

Second as you would for the effect to operate to close a tab and then there will be the following newly tab

```
if ($('#sidebar ul').length) {
    $("#sidebar ul").accordion({
        event: "mouseover",
        active: 1,
        collapsible: false,
        autoHeight: false
    });
}
```

Example URL: http://jsfiddle.net/8pKMh/

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559539/change-animation-speed-of-jquery-ui-accordion

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want, regarding the second problem. Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the speed, use [animate](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-animate):

```
if ($('#sidebar ul').length) {
    $("#sidebar ul").accordion({
        event: "mouseover",
        active: 1,
        collapsible: false,
        autoHeight: false,
        animate: 2000 // miliseconds
    });
}​
```

From the jquery ui docs:

**Animate**

If and how to animate changing panels.

**Multiple types supported:**

- Boolean: A value of false will disable animations.
- Number: Duration in milliseconds with default easing.
- String: Name of easing to use with default duration.
- Object: Animation settings with easing and duration properties.

  - Can also contain a down property with any of the above options.
  - "Down" animations occur when the panel being activated has a lower index than the currently active panel.

Comment: Your code is ok but I see a problem with a tab that has several items the effect moves very fast when you leave the tab # 3 to the # 2 and vicersa tab with the other items http://jsfiddle.net/8pKMh/7/

Comment: @RaulValverde Hmm, you're right. It looks like a bug with the autoHeight (if it's `false` it works better, but probably doesn't look like you want it to).

Comment: Although the example is false you believe that there is a solution by another method capable?

Comment: @RaulValverde nope, sorry. I'm using my mobile, so it's hard to help out right now. Try searching the Web for the bug, maybe?

Comment: Ok Mario, any other suggestions